# Where should I store my application's TrayIcon?

Tags: c#, wpf

I still have the problem that I don't know where to store my `TrayIcon`.
Basically the thing is, if Windows is going to start my program from the "autostart"... it crashed. I found out that my given path to the TrayIcon is the problem. I load the TrayIcon by using this command in C# WPF:

```
NotifiIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(@"icon.ico");
```

Because there is no problem at the whole manual startup process (double click on the .exe file). But, when I try to let the program start from the Windows registry on Startup, the program crashes. The problem seems to be that the autostart process could not find the Icon. Next I tried this:

```
NotifiIcon.Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\icon.ico");
```

But the same thing happenedd.

So, two things where I'm going to find the best way (hopefully):

1. Is there a way to solve the problem without using a Windows Directory to store the Icon, or
2. Is there a save location on any Windows System to store my Icon?

Comment: You could store and access the icon as an embedded resource, or in a resource file. This basically includes the icon itself in the generated assembly. You don't need to know any paths other than your assembly's namespace.

Comment: The two snippets are identical and have the exact same problem, kaboom when the CurrentDirectory is not where you hope it is.  Do use a resource first, Assembly.Location next.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. I solved the Problem, by using "Drag&Drop" to add the icon to my "Images" folder. Next, i was setting up the path to: `Stream iconStream = System.Windows.Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/sqldbmb.ico")).Stream;` That worked!

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not use `Environment.CurrentDirectory` but `Application.StartupPath` instead.

If you do the following, it will work:

```
 _trayIcon = new NotifyIcon
        {
            Text = "Some application text",
            Icon = new Icon(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "icon.ico"), DefaultMaximumSize),
            Visible = true
        };
```